# Haskell – SPOJ – Code 'TEST'

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve the first SPOJ-problem in Haskell, but always end up having a parse error on input `if`. Is this a common problem?

```
main = do input <- getLine
      if input == "42" then putStr "" 
      else do putStrLn input
              main
```

Comment: Always try your SPOJ code on [ideone](https://ideone.com/). They are using the same engine, but here you'll get detailed compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had the same problem solving SPOJ problems. Your editor probably mixes tabs and spaces. Try to use spaces only and everything will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indentation, try this:

```
main = do input <- getLine
      if input == "42" 
         then putStr "" 
         else do putStrLn input
              main
```